# Can't use pipes with hdfs

Tags: bash, hdfs

I can't manage to use hdfs dfs within a pipe operators correctly.

```bash
[[ 'hdfs dfs -test -f "$hdfs_path"' ]] && echo "file exists" || echo "file doesn't exist"
```

This returns file exists always regardless of file existing or not.

If I use it without brackets:

```bash
[[ hdfs dfs -test -f "$hdfs_path" ]] && echo "file exists" || echo "file doesn't exist"
```

I get this error: `bash: syntax error near dfs'`

This does work:

```bash
[[ -f "$path" ]] && echo "file exists" || echo "file doesn't exist"
```

Not sure how to do this.

Comment: What happens if you remove the brackets entirely ?

Comment: This worked..., makes sense as -test already implies it. thanks!

Comment: [cross site duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22726/how-to-conditionally-do-something-if-a-command-succeeded-or-failed). There probably is one on this site, but I didn't find it

Comment: There is no pipe in the code you posted. I don't understand your question.

Comment: @user1934428 OP probably mistook `||` for pipes

Answer (score 0):

```
if hdfs dfs -test -f "$hdfs_path"; then
    echo file exists
else
    echo file does not exist
fi
```

Don't use test brackets to run a command. Chaining `&&` and `||` is not equivalent to an if statement.

Comment: This seems to work for me apparently:

`hdfs dfs -test -f "$hdfs_path"  && echo "file exists" || echo "file doesn't exist"`

Comment: It is equivalent to an if statement in OP's case though

Comment: @Aserre No it's not. If the first echo fails, the second echo is executed (even though `hdfs` succeeded). That is not the same as an if statement.